# Looking for a way to sign PDFs

Tags: pdf, signature, rdesktop

I am looking for a working method to sign PDFs using the certificate
from a signature card.

So what I need is either a program that signs PDFs in a way that is compatible
to what AcroRead does on Microsoft, or a way to forward the signature card via
rdesktop.

Comment: Can you specify what format the signature card is in, and which kind of signature you want to apply?

Comment: @AdminBee are there different formats?The driver for the cardreader is present and firefox has been manually instructed to load the shared lib that suports the signature.

Comment: Is LibreOffice available to you? It would seem to have [such a function](https://kamarada.github.io/en/2020/03/13/signing-odf-and-pdf-documents-with-libreoffice/).

Comment: OK, I would need to che check whether libreoffice recognizes my card and cardreader... Thank you for the hint. I will check this in a few days when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have your signature recognized by Firefox, then poppler can be used to sign PDFs with certificates:

1. Install poppler (`sudo apt install poppler-utils` on Debian systems)
2. List the signature nicknames available to you from Firefox:

```
pdfsig -list-nicks
```

3. Apply the signature to the specified field in the document (either by field name or index in the document):

```
pdfsig -nick <NICKNAME> -sign <FIELD> <INPUT-PDF> <OUTPUT-PDF>
```

If you are looking to apply signatures to a document that *does not* have signature fields then that's also possible, but because of the way you asked your question I suspect that's not what you are looking for.

Comment: For your information, your suggested edit on [Setting up Squid transparent proxy with SSL bumping on Debian 10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/678561/80216) was rejected by the author of the post. See the comments there.